# Scan through HTML table on the OnPost method of a razor page

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Good morning, I am developing my web application in .Net 3.1 and Razor pages. In one of my pages I have a table with some input fields in various columns that the user can modify to his liking.

```
<table id="myTbl" class="display nowrap table-sm table-striped table-hover table-bordered" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
        <th>Col6</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var prop in Model.Props)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@prop.Unitid</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="@Model.Method1(prop.Unitid)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="@Model.Method2(prop.Unitid)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="@Model.Method3(prop.Unitid)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="@Model.Method4(prop.Unitid)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxV" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "V")" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxV" + prop.Unitid)">V</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxW" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "W")" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxW" + prop.Unitid)">W</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxS" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "S")" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxS" + prop.Unitid)">S</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxP" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "P")" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxP" + prop.Unitid)">P</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxA" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "A")" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxA" + prop.Unitid)">A</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxM" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "M")" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxM" + prop.Unitid)">M</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxU" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "U")" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxU" + prop.Unitid)">U</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxD" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "D")" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxD" + prop.Unitid)">D</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</tbody>
```

In my page I also have a button with which I would like to scan through all the rows of my table and pass the values of said row to a method that, if some conditions are met for that specific row, it updates the DB using EF Core with the data from the fields of said row.

What is the best practice to obtain my goal? Can I associate the entire table to a model property and scan through the rows in my model?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can. Use a viewmodel to pass the table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best practice to obtain my goal? Can I associate the entire table to a model property and scan through the rows in my model?

To achieve above requirement, you can make your handler method `OnPost` accept a parameter, and specify `name` attribute for your input field(s) to match properties of custom model class, which would help bind value to properties of the model automatically.

Custom Model class

```
public class MyCustomModel
{
    public int Unitid { get; set; }
    public bool Col2Checked { get; set; }
    public bool Col3Checked { get; set; }
    public string Col4Val { get; set; }
    public string Col5Val { get; set; }

    public Col6Childs Col6Val { get; set; }
}

public class Col6Childs
{
    public bool IsV { get; set; }
    public bool IsW { get; set; }
    public bool IsS { get; set; }
    public bool IsP { get; set; }
    public bool IsA { get; set; }
    public bool IsM { get; set; }
    public bool IsU { get; set; }
    public bool IsD { get; set; }
}
```

Handler method

```
public IActionResult OnPost(List<MyCustomModel> myCustomModel)
{
    //code logic here
    //...
```

In Page

```
<form method="post">
    <table id="myTbl" class="display nowrap table-sm table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
                <th>Col4</th>
                <th>Col5</th>
                <th>Col6</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var prop in Model.Props)
            {


                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @prop.Unitid
                        <input type="hidden" name="myCustomModel[@index].Unitid" value="@prop.Unitid">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="@Model.Method1(prop.Unitid)" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col2Checked" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="@Model.Method2(prop.Unitid)" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col3Checked" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="@Model.Method3(prop.Unitid)" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col4Val" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="@Model.Method4(prop.Unitid)" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col5Val" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxV" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "V")" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsV" value="true" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsV" value="false" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxV" + prop.Unitid)">V</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxW" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "W")" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsW" value="true" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsW" value="false" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxW" + prop.Unitid)">W</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxS" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "S")" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsS" value="true" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsS" value="false" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxS" + prop.Unitid)">S</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxP" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "P")" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsP" value="true" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsP" value="false" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxP" + prop.Unitid)">P</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxA" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "A")" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsA" value="true" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsA" value="false" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxA" + prop.Unitid)">A</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxM" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "M")" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsM" value="true" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsM" value="false" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxM" + prop.Unitid)">M</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxU" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "U")" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsU" value="true" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsU" value="false" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxU" + prop.Unitid)">U</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@("checkBoxD" + prop.Unitid)" class="custom-control-input" checked="@Model.Method5(prop.Unitid, "D")" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsD" value="true" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="myCustomModel[@index].Col6Val.IsD" value="false" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="@("checkBoxD" + prop.Unitid)">D</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

               index++;     
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: You are using many Checkboxes in your page, and [this article](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes) explained how to use Checkboxes in a Razor Pages Form, you can refer to it.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try and get back to you with any doubt. I think I won't have any though, your example is super clear!

Comment: I had to adapt it to my specific situation but the concept worked perfectly! Thank you very much!